# program.exe stops working on large input

Tags: arrays, c++11

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>
#include<bitset>
#include<cstring>
#include<sstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
int d1[] = { 0,0,1,-1,1,-1 ,1,-1 };
int d2[] = { -1,1,0,0,1 ,-1,-1,1 };
string vec[200 + 5];
int counter = 0;
long long int floodfill(int n1, int n2, char c1, char c2,int ss)
{
    if (n1 < 0 || n1 >= ss || n2 < 0||n2>=vec[n1].length())
        return 0;
    if (vec[n1][n2] != c1) return 0;

    long long int ans = 1;
    vec[n1][n2] = c2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        ans = ans + floodfill(n1 + d2[i], n2 + d1[i], c1, c2,ss);
    return ans;
}
int floodfill2(int n1, int n2, char c1, char c2,int ss)
{
    if (n1 < 0 || n1 >= ss || n2 < 0 || n2 >= vec[n1].length())
        return 0;
    if (vec[n1][n2] == '0')
    {
        floodfill(n1, n2, '0', c1,ss);
        counter++;
    }
    if (vec[n1][n2] !=c1) return 0;
    int ans = 1;
    vec[n1][n2] = c2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        ans = ans + floodfill2(n1 + d1[i], n2 + d2[i], c1, c2,ss);
    return ans;
}
int main() {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int co = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> n1;
        cin >> n2;
        if (n1 == 0 && n2 == 0)
            break;
        getchar();
        int aa = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            char s[300];
            scanf("%s", s);
            string g = "";
            int a = strlen(s);
            for (int j = 0; j <a; j++)
            {
                string temp = "";
                if (s[j] == '0')
                    temp = "0000";
                else if (s[j] == '1')
                    temp = "0001";
                else if (s[j] == '2')
                    temp = "0010";
                else if (s[j] == '3')
                    temp = "0011";
                else if (s[j] == '4')
                    temp = "0100";
                else if (s[j] == '5')
                    temp = "0101";
                else if (s[j] == '6')
                    temp = "0110";
                else if (s[j] == '7')
                    temp = "0111";
                else if (s[j] == '8')
                    temp = "1000";
                else if (s[j] == '9')
                    temp = "1001";
                else if (s[j] == 'a')
                    temp = "1010";
                else if (s[j] == 'b')
                    temp = "1011";
                else if (s[j] == 'c')
                    temp = "1100";
                else if (s[j] == 'd')
                    temp = "1101";
                else if (s[j] == 'e')
                    temp = "1110";
                else if (s[j] == 'f')
                    temp = "1111";
                g =g+ temp;
            }
            vec[aa] = g;
            aa++;
        }
        floodfill(0, 0, '0', '.',aa);
        string ans = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < aa; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < vec[0].length(); j++)
            {
                counter = 0;
                if (vec[i][j] == '1')
                {
                    floodfill2(i, j, '1', '.',aa);
                    if (counter == 0)
                        ans = ans + 'W';
                    else if (counter == 1)
                        ans = ans + 'A';
                    else if (counter == 2)
                        ans = ans + 'K';
                    else if (counter == 3)
                        ans = ans + 'J';
                    else if (counter == 4)
                        ans = ans + 'S';
                    else if (counter == 5)
                        ans = ans + 'D';
                }
            }
        }
        sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
        cout << "Case " << co  << ": " << ans << endl;
        co++;

    }
}
```

it work on this input

```
6 25
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
00001fe0000000000007c0000
00003fe0000000000007c0000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
```

but stops working on this one

```
200 50
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Run in debugger and find out where it 'stops working'

Comment: when i call floodfill the first time

Comment: At what line does it "stop working"?

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
string vec[200 + 5];
...
if (vec[n1][n2] != c1) return 0;
```

I cannot see that you are checking that this array never goes out of bounds i.e that the code attempts to access an element greater than 205.

I expect that with your large input, you are going out of bonds.

An easy way to check is to run the debug build.  A decent debug c runtime library should give you an explicit out of bounds error.

Otherwise, you can add something like this:

```
#define MAXSIZE 204
string vec[ MAXSIZE];
...
if( n1 >= MAXSIZE )
{
   cout << "ERROR: Input too big\n";
   exit(1);
}
```